# How to uninstall Heroku Toolbelt from OS X?

Tags: heroku, uninstallation

I installed Heroku Toolbelt, and discovered I don't know how to uninstall it.
How can I uninstall it cleanly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just do:

```
rm -rf ~/.heroku
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/heroku
sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/heroku
```

to remove the relevant files and folders

Answer (score 3):

Currently I installed heroku-cli by MacOSX pkg.
I tried [Official documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#uninstalling-the-heroku-cli-macos) commands, but cannot be uninstalled.
I check directories using `find -type d -name heroku`, I found `/usr/local/lib/heroku`.

So you can run here I think:

```
# Cache and settings
rm -rf ~/.cache/heroku
rm -rf ~/.config/heroku
rm -rf ~/.local/share/heroku
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/heroku

# Symlink and main sources
rm /usr/local/bin/heroku
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/heroku
```

Answer (score 1):

Run these two commands:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/heroku
sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/heroku
```

Answer (score 0):

The following command should find everything related to heroku

```
$ sudo find / -name "*heroku*" -prune 2>/dev/null
```

From the result list I found that I needed to delete the following

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/heroku
sudo rm -rf /private/var/db/receipts/com.heroku.toolbelt.bom
sudo rm -rf /private/var/db/receipts/com.heroku.toolbelt.plist
rm -rf ~/.config/heroku
rm -rf ~/.heroku
rm -rf ~/.local/share/heroku
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/heroku
rm -rf ~/.cache/heroku
```

Also don't forget to remove the heroku command from your `PATH`. So delete the following line from your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/heroku/bin/:$PATH
```